# Minimum amount of data needed for low pass filter on real time sensor data

Tags: lowpass-filter, fourier, sensor

I need to apply a low pass filter up to a period of 10 hours to my data. My sensor has a sampling rate of 1 sample every 5 minutes. I need to know how much data I at least need to have to be allowed to use a lowpass filter.

Fourier is fairly new to me, but I would say that I need at least 10 hours of data (so 120 datapoints), is this correct?

Comment: There is no organized low pass filter police force.  As long as you have at least two samples, you can apply something that is validly called a low pass filter to it.

Answer (score 1):

A linear filter will usually produce output with only a single input sample.

The «validity» of early output depends on the degree of filtering and what analysis you are doing on the output.

Sometimes a filter can be «kickstarted» to produce early samples that stands less out.

edit:

Say that you are working on a signal that contains an unknown constant (1 in this case) on top of which is a zero-mean gaussian additive noise of some variance.

You want to estimate that unknown constant. How many samples do you need?

```
N = 100;
x = 0.1*randn(N, 1) + 1;
alpha = 0.05;
y1 = filter(alpha, [1 -(1-alpha)], x);
z = filtic(b, a, x(1), x(1));
y2 = filter(b, a, x, z);
y3 = cumsum(x)./(1:N)';
```

[image: 3 different smoothing approaches]

For this case it seems that the "growing mean" can reach the unknown mean "quite well" after 5 samples or so.

In other cases, you might have steps or ramps in the signal that lends itself to other approaches.

Comment: It should be stated that there is something called transient phase / settling time in the context of filters.